# How to sort List within another list using linq in vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have 2 generic lists.

```
  Dim Item As New List(Of String)
  Dim Item2 As New List(Of Array)
```

Item conatains 4 elements.

They are 1. Item code
         2. Description
         3. BIN
         4. Price

But they are just entered sequentially
For example

Item={5858545, HairDryer, A45, 50}

There are many Item and Item 2 contains The list of Items.
For example Item2= {{5858545, HairDryer, A45, 50},....}

Now i want to sort the Item2 according to according to the BIN and then By Item code

So now my list Item2 will contains elements  of Item sorted according to BIN and then By Item code.

How to do this with LINQ or any other way?

Thanks

Comment: I would strongly recommend creating a class for `Item1` instead of an array of strings.  It will make your code much cleaner.

Comment: You use an object-oriented language, you should make a better use of objects in your code. For example, you can create an Item class with properties ItemCode, Description, Bin, Price... This will greatly simplify your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be storing objects as an array or list of values.  Create a new class to represent your item.  Give it four properties for BIN, name, etc., and then create a list of that custom type.

To order the list you can use the `OrderBy` method, followed by the `ThenBy` method.  It will read much better if you have a custom object, as it will look like:

```
list.OrderBy(item => item.BIN).ThenBy(item => item.Code);
```

instead of the much uglier option you need to do if you have arrays/lists:

```
list.OrderBy(item => item[0]).ThenBy(item => item[1]);
```

Note how the first example reads *exactly* like your requirements.  "Order the list by BIN and then by Code."  It's perfectly clear to someone looking at the code for the first time *exactly* what it's doing.

Comment: Yes i know this is bad to use list but the main problem is if i ahve to change the list to class then i have to change in many parts of the code

Comment: @user2008654 That's why you should make an effort to add designs like this at the start.  Even so though, if this is used in a lot of places it's all the more important that a class be used instead of an array.  Currently the code is most likely a mess, very hard to comprehend and reason able, much harder to maintain and expand on, and lacking a lot of compile time checking that it ought to have.

Comment: Thanks very much it worked i will try to implement it as class